# Is there any way to get the latest TalkBack source code?

Tags: android, talkback

I would like to customize google [TalkBack](https://github.com/google/talkback) for some reasons. The latest open source code version in GitHub is 6.1 but in devices, we are getting 7.3.0.239841594. Is there any way to get the latest source code of version 7.3.0.239841594.

Comment: Please keep in mind that even if you modify some functionality, you should rely on the official implementation. The users will be using the official unmodified version of `TalkBack`.

Comment: Did you get a more updated version of talkback? I'm still seeing the 6.1 version :(

Comment: Did anybody find more recent code?

Answer (score 0):

As of today you can get the source code at  https://github.com/google/talkback